# Why did no one notice the ghost's absence?

Tags: boo-bitch

In the series *Boo Bitch*, we find out that

> Gia

has been killed and has only been present as a ghost for the whole show, with only Erika and Gavin able to see her due to their relation to her unfinished business (along with Gavin's apparent ghost-viewing powers).

Apparently, Gia had no friends except Erika (and vice versa), but that would still mean that by the end of the show, Gia would have been marked as absent from classes for about a month, which tends to lead to contacting a student's family; moreover, said family would not have seen her during that time. One might think that this would have resulted in a missing persons search and police questioning students at the school, but no one seemed to notice that Gia was missing until Erika pointed out that she was dead at the prom.

Why did no one notice Gia's absence during this period?

Answer (score 2):

If you remember in the beginning of the series, Gia’s mom was out of the country for a while. She was also 18, so when it came to questioning for school, they either probably didn’t (because it’s the end of the year, good grades, and she probably had perfect attendance so it would be even longer before anyone finds it suspicious). Plus she was able to use the phone so she was texting her mom and Erika, and was video chatting Erika. So they probably didn’t have anyone to report her missing, because she was talking to the only people who would’ve noticed her go missing